# HSTS header for all resources? or documents?

Tags: performance, security, http, hsts

Do I have to return a *HTTP Strict Transport Security* header for all resources (stylesheets, scripts, images) loaded with my documents? or is it enough to include them for the documents only?

The security hint should be applied per-domain, so just sending it with the documents should be enough to inform the browser to only fetch resources over HTTPS? Or have I misunderstood how it is supposed to work?

Anyone only accessing my site’s resources directly are not really an audience I want to cater specifically for anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it should be enough to send the header for documents.

> If a UA receives HTTP responses from a Known HSTS Host over a secure channel but the responses are missing the STS header field, the UA MUST continue to treat the host as a Known HSTS Host until the max-age value for the knowledge of that Known HSTS Host is reached.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797#section-8.6

Hoping clients have implemented the RFC correctly.

**Update:** Here is the Apache configuration I used. I unset it for resources instead of setting it for documents specifically to make sure the header is used in redirects and other pages generated by Apache.

```
# Enable HSTS for all responses, but disable for common resources
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=324000; includeSubDomains"
<FilesMatch "\.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png|woff)$">
    Header unset Strict-Transport-Security
</FilesMatch>
```

Shaves off 64 bytes from each resource’s response headers.

Comment: 324000 is only 3.75 days. Wouldn't you want the `max-age` to be at least a month, if not a year?